Power automate - How to copy the Excel cell comment from workbook1 to workbook2
Good day. Need help.
I have an Excel table1 in workbook1 contains list of servers by department. Some of the cells (the servers) in the table1 have comments added by "Add Comments" option.
I have another Excel table2 in workbook2 contains the servers (the master list).
I want to transfer(copy) the comments on the cell of table1 to table2 if the server matches using power automate. Meaning that the AuthorName, CreationDate, Content will be copied over to the table2 and appear as Comment as well. Could this be done?

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

OfficeScript can read properties like AuthorName and CreationDate, but it doesn't provide the capability to modify these values when adding or creating new comments on cells. The values of AuthorName and CreationDate are automatically generated by the system.
